# Htaccess bug - rule for page navigation

Tags: .htaccess

htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_p([0-9]+).html$   $1.html?_pn=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$        index.php?param=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Input url - http://localhost/blabla/blablabla.html

Result

```
Array
(
    [param] => blabla/blablabla
)
```

But for 
Input url - http://localhost/blabla/blablabla_p2.html

Result

```
Array
(
    [param] => blabla/blablabla.html/blabla/blablabla_p2
    [_pn] => 2
)
```

What is this "/blabla/blablabla_p2"

But I need

```
Array
(
    [param] => blabla/blablabla
    [_pn] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `[L]` behind the first `RewriteRule`.

Otherwise, rewriting will continue and your newly rewritten URL from rule one is passed on to rule two.